# How can I make an iOS app go back to initialVC when a user opens the app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to make my app go back to the initialVC when a user clicks on the app. Right now when I run my app on the simulator and go to hardware -> home and click back on the app to open it, the view that is displayed is the view that I left when going on the simulator home page, not the VC I want it to display. I'd love to get some help from some more experienced developers. Thanks guys!

Update: Alright, after playing around a little bit with @Christian Woerz solution, I've come to understand this;

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

// Here when instituting my VC, the string I pass it is the "storyboardID" I gave my VC. Then the type has to be the VC I want to show.
    if let myController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as? ViewController {

// I may be wrong, but isn't there something that's supposed to go before "presentViewController"?

        presentViewController(myController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

After understanding a little more what's going on, I have a new question. If the VC I want to show is embedded in a navigationController, should I show the navigationController instead?

Comment: Why? If the user leaves your app for just a second, do they really want to start over?

Comment: You will need to make use of the AppDelegate.swift file.

Answer (score 3):

In your `AppDelegate.swift` to `func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)` add:

```
let nc = window.rootViewController as UINavigationController
nc.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

This only works if your root view controller is a `UINavigationController`.

If you don’t have a `UINavigationController` you should be able to:

```
window.rootViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: false)
```

Comment: Converted it to Swift.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `AppDelegate.swift` file. In there, you find the method:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication!) {

}
```

This method gets called, everytime your application enters the background. So you can add a function to show the ViewController. But first you have to access your storyboard:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

After that, you can use the `storyboard` to access your ViewController.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication!) {
  if let yourController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourId") as? ResultViewController {
      presentViewController(yourController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

But you have to add an identifier to your `ViewController` The nice thing about that is, that you can call every ViewController and not just the rootviewcontroller:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense to me now that you say it, but when I do this it gives me an error saying ***used of unresolved identifier "storyboard"***

Comment: Yes, because you have to specify the storyboard in Appdelegate to get your storyboard. I updated my answer: var `storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())`

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. I did just as you said and now I get an error "used of undeclared type ResultViewController".

Comment: Yes, because you have to edit the code I've written. that's a sample code. Your ViewController's name isn't ResultViewController. So you have to put your own controller in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your patience, it's appreciated. I'm still having some issues but I'll try to figure it out myself before asking for some more help. If I'm having too much trouble I'll come back.

Comment: Ok, I've tried playing around with the code for a while. This is beyond my knowledge for now. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel as if there should be something before 'presentViewController'. I've updated my question above also with what my thoughts and understanding are. Thanks again!

Comment: This will present new VCs on top of what is there, eventually you will use quite a lot of unnecessary memory and likely get killed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation, implement [`applicationWillEnterForeground`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:) and you can pop stuff off your navigation stack, or do whatever, there.